# curentamount is not defined, no-undef, when I increment value using createSlice Reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, redux-toolkit

In `reduxSlice` file, I am getting an error - **'curentamount' is not defined  no-undef**.

**Redux slice:**

```js
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const addtoSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'addto',
  initialState: {
    curentamount: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    incriment: (state) => {
      state.curentamount = curentamount + 1
    },
    decriment: (state) => {
      state.curentamount = curentamount - 1
    },
  },
})

export const { incriment, decriment } = addtoSlice.actions

export const selectadto = (state) => state.addtoSlice.curentamount

export default addtoSlice.reducer
```

**React Component:**

```
import React from 'react'
import addList from './features/auth/ads.json'

const Addtocart = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {addList.map((add) => (
        <div key={add.id}>
          <div> {add.addname}</div>
          <div> {add.price}</div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Addtocart
```

**Error Message:**

```
Failed to compile.

src/features/auth/addtoSlice.js
  Line 11:34:  'curentamount' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 14:34:  'curentamount' is not defined  no-undef
```

Comment: @AjeetShah ,it worked tq,  can you put this as the answer so I can choose your answer

Comment: I added an answer. Isn't there a spelling mistake in "incriment" and "curentamount"? It should be "currentAmount" and "increment". Not important but it makes code more readable.

Comment: @AjeetShah yes there is a mistake, tq for pointing it out ,I updated it,

Comment: @AjeetShah updated another question , if possible please check, can check in my profile

Comment: @AjeetShah  , updated a question in my wall please check if possible tq

Comment: @AjeetShah  added a new question would you be able to check it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curentamount` is not defined at line `state.curentamount = curentamount + 1`. You can write any of these:

```js
state.curentamount++
state.curentamount += 1
state.curentamount = state.curentamount + 1
```

Or, read `changeBy` value from the payload (if you are sending it):

```js
incriment: (state, action) => {
  state.curentamount += action.payload.changeBy
},
```

An example to send `changeBy` in payload:

```
// in a component
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(incriment({ changeBy: 10 }))
}, [dispatch])
```